# How To Set Text Size To A Double

Tags: java, android, android-studio, double, textview

So I am trying to set the text size of a `TextView` to a `double` variable.

Android Studio doesn't like it as it requires a `float` variable, but the size of these letters have to be exact as the project is for a medical company.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I have now implemented the suggestion below, but the text does not show up on the screen. Here is the code below:

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
String PREFS_NAME = "VALUES";
int DEF_VAL = 0;
double final_calc1;
double final_calc2;
double DIST_SCALE = 0;
double size = DIST_SCALE * 2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences DIST = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int f1 = DIST.getInt("value1", DEF_VAL);
    int f2 = DIST.getInt(value2", DEF_VAL);
    final_calc1 = f2 / 12;
    final_calc2 = final_calc1 + f1;
    DIST_SCALE = final_calc2 * .1875;
    //were everything is scaled based on the values ^^^
    //I am also positive that shared references is getting the required
    //values, I tested that part earlier
    setContentView(R.layout.standard_400);
    TextView letter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.standard_400_line1);
    letter.setTextSize((float) size);


}
}
```

When I load it up and run it in the emulator nothing appears, any ideas how I can fix this?
Thanks again!

Comment: `size = DIST_SCALE * 2` and `DIST_SCALE = 0` **=>**  `size = 0`, Thats why your text is not shown. You need to recalculate the `size` after changing `DIST_SCALE` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your `double` variable will be used to set the *text size*, so it will be small enough to fit in `float`.

I suggest you to just cast your `double` to `float`, eg:

```
double d = 24.64;
yourTextView.setTextSize( (float) d);
```

**Notice:**

float

> 4 bytes, IEEE 754.
>
> Covers a range from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38
>   (positive or negative).

double

> 8 bytes IEEE 754.
>
> Covers a range from 4.94065645841246544e-324d to
>   1.79769313486231570e+308d (positive or negative).